# How do I drop an entire database and recreate it using sql and c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a script that allows me to connect to a sql db, create the db to a textfile and then drop then entire database. Once this is done I would like to be able to re-create the entire database. Is this possible?

Comment: When you say re-create the database do you still need the data or simply the object schema?

Comment: What's the point? (i.e. please explain the motivation there might be easier ways to achieve your end goal)

Comment: it is but it is a tun of work.  You have to itereate over a tun of thins... triggers... view... stored procs... tables... functions... users... etc...   Why not do a backup and restore that is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace to [generate a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205738.aspx), just like you would in ssms.  It might take a few tries to get the [ScriptingOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.aspx) right, so don't get over zealous and start dropping things right away.

Once you've generated your script, it would be a simple `ExecuteNonQuery("drop database foo")` to drop your database.

To recreate, use the same namespace to execute the script. Using a normal `ExecuteNonQuery` will not work because the script will contain "GO", which is not valid sql.  The SMO does contain logic to handle that though.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\script.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection ));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

This is assumed, of course, to be logged in with a user that has adequate permissions on the sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your purpose but you could use a database project
see

- [Manage Database Projects With Visual Studio 2010](http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/08/manage-database-projects-with-visual-studio-2010/)
- [Creating SQL Server Objects in Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997440.aspx)
- [Working with Database
  Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx)

with this you can recreate a database on demand.